# Rails4 Strong Parameters, how permit associative array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

view(haml):

```
- kind.apanages.each do |apanage|
  = number_field_tag "fact[apanage[#{apanage.id}]]", ''
```

controller:

1 . Don't use permit:

```
render :json => params
```

> {"utf8":"✓","fact":{"entity_id":"27","apanage":{"1":"7","2":"13","3":"2","4":"1","6":"20","7":"23","8":"10",}},"commit":"End","action":"facts","controller":"entities"}

2 . Use permit (var 1):

```
render :json => params.require(:fact).permit(:entity_id, :apanage => [])
```

> {"entity_id":"27"}

3 . Use permit (var 2):

```
render :json => params.require(:fact).permit(:entity_id, apanage: [:id, :content])
```

> {"entity_id":"27","apanage":{}}

How I can permit array 'apanage'?

Comment: Can you give me some more context? Why are you including this out of the scope of the passed params?

Comment: More info about my problem here  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454
Thanks @zishe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
params.require(:fact).permit(:entity_id).permit!(:apanage)
```

Also look at [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454).